# Eclipse, import multi Maven module project programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, powershell

I have been working on the multi Maven module project, and during import process we don't import the parent project. Is there any way to import multi Maven module programmatically (Java)? Is it possible to use PowerShell for this? I also would like to set Window > Preferences > Maven > Errors/Warnings > Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration. Select Ignore / Warning / Error to avoid parent-pom errors by using java code or PowerShell somehow.

I have found some links which use IProjectConfigurationManager for this purpose, but I'm not sure is that the right way:

http://massapi.com/source/github/33/10/33103309/core/plugins/org.fusesource.ide.maven/src/org/fusesource/ide/maven/MavenFacade.java.html#TOP

http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IProjectConfigurationManager

Could you please show some code examples? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you import the parent project? It's start level of your multi module build and will bring it to work in Eclipse...and why do you need to do it programmatically..just goto import in Eclipse Maven and select the location and import it? What kid of problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: Thank you for your interest and attention. Both are Project Architect's requests: import without parent project and import process implemented  programmatically. So please provide some code examples if you can. Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry to say that but these requirements make no sense...Use the existing tools and how they work. That makes life easier..and does not cost efforts which are simply useless...